# Programatically connecting to a website on a server from another website

Tags: javascript, server

Is it possible to connect a server to a website, where I can access the server from another website and if I click submit, it programmatically clicks a button on the website connected to the server?
 Is this possible to do in Javascript(if not, any idea on how to implement this?)

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to emulate a browser action with server-side code?

Comment: So you're looking to trigger a `DOM` event on a different website to the one in which you're interacting with? What are your limitations? Do you have access to both websites, or are you trying to automate an action on a 3rd party website?

Comment: Hi, Im not sure. Say I have an email account connected to a server, is it possible from an external website to send requests to the server to do some action on that  gmail account?

Comment: @user1783326: Anything that can make HTTP requests can "connect" to a website.

Comment: Look into web sockets and javascript bookmarklets

Comment: Is it possible to connect the gmail account to the server such that as long as the server is live the gmail account is always logged in?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible on any development environment I used this in C# Asp.net and in python. Simply you can use a WebClient object in asp.net. You can click any button and you can set any area on target machine like for user login name and password. Even robot control on logins is exist just for this reason

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/488939/Get-page-HTML-from-URL-using-WebClient-Strip-HTML

[Can't login into asp.net website with WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906771/cant-login-into-asp-net-website-with-webclient)

Comment: As an example, is it possible to connect a gmail account to a server - and if I click on a submit button on an external website, that results in some action on my gmail account? 
 Also is it possible to have the gmail account always live as long as the server is live?

Comment: You can see by trying but if you clicked the button with webclient on external site it is a mirror click from the orginal website and the action reales like a real user logged and clicked. In essentially when you debuged this event on target machine: fires not a real user clicked on document object model, you can see events sender is not a real user. Even you can change event sender in jscript by the event fragmentation manner. And this is an open door any website...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments you've provided, your question seems to be specific to gmail. If that is the case, google offers an API that will let you perform operations from your code that would normally be performed by a user.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/

From the site:

> What is the Gmail API?
>
> The Gmail API gives you flexible, RESTful access to the user's inbox,
>   with a natural interface to Threads, Messages, Labels, Drafts, and
>   History. From the modern language of your choice, your app can use the
>   API to add Gmail features like:
>
> - Read messages from Gmail
> - Send email messages
> - Modify the labels applied to messages and threads
> - Search for specific messages and threads